# To show that a sequence where the absolute value of the difference of two terms is greater 0, the sequence has no convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I came across this question, which basically said:

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a sequence such that for some $\epsilon>0$:

$$|a_{n} - a_{m}| \ge \epsilon \ \ \text{ for all }n \ne m.$$

We need to prove that $\{a_n\}$ has no convergent subsequence.

I am unsure as to how to go about this, since $n$ and $m$ can be any arbitrary value right?

Comment: Are you familiar with Cauchy sequences?

Comment: I am, but I have no idea as to how to present the formal proof.

Comment: Use the fact that convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences.

Comment: How though? How will that show that this has no convergent subsequence?

Comment: Try to argue by contradiction.

Comment: Can I just state the Cauchy sequence theorem?

Comment: Sorry, I know that a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence. But I don't know if the opposite is true, so I don't know how to argue this by contradiction

Comment: It's not about Cauchy sequences having a convergent subsequence. It's about convergent subsequences being Cauchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are willing to use the fact that in a complete space a sequence is convergent iff it is Cauchy, we can prove this simply.

By definition, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is not Cauchy. It also immediately follows that no subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ can be Cauchy (To see why suppose a given subsequence is Cauchy. Then for some $N$ such that $\alpha,\beta >N$, we have $|a_{n_\alpha} - a_{n_\beta}| \leq \epsilon$. But this contradicts the given property of $\{a_n\}$)

Hence every subsequence is not Cauchy, and so is not convergent.